# how to make zoom effect on imageview in Android studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-imageview

I tried [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_lmRQB58r-U) tutorial to put the zoom effect on my `ImageView` , but when I compile this it is not zooming always.

Comment: what type of zoom you want i mean by touch or automatically by time

Answer (score 0):

Do you want that zoom style.

paste follwing code in animator folder with anyname

```
  <set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

           <objectAnimator
                 android:duration="1000"
                 android:interpolator="@android:interpolator/accelerate_decelerate"
                 android:propertyName="scaleY"
                 android:valueFrom="1"
                 android:valueTo="1.5"
                 android:repeatCount="infinite"
                 android:repeatMode="reverse"
                 />

          <objectAnimator
              android:duration="1000"
              android:interpolator="@android:interpolator/accelerate_decelerate"
              android:propertyName="scaleX"
              android:valueFrom="1"
              android:valueTo="1.5"
              android:repeatCount="infinite"
              android:repeatMode="reverse"
             />
  </set>
```

in your activity

```
   Animator animation = AnimatorInflater.loadAnimator(getApplicationContext(), R.animator.selectzoom);//select zoom is the file name of your animator xml file
   animation.setTarget(imageView);
   animation.start();
```

Try it once hoping it will work

Comment: i dont want animation just zoom when we tuch.

Comment: android:repeatCount="1"//instead of infinete         and delete the repeatmode

Comment: The other code it is for java activity?what can i import because they show error.

Comment: when i put the code in java code i have animator ,setTarget(imageview) and start have same error can not resolve symbol'  ' but i dont want this kind of zoom i whant when we touch screen we have zoom

Answer (score 0):

Create a `ZoomInZoomOut` class first:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Matrix;
import android.graphics.PointF;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.FloatMath;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnTouchListener;
import android.widget.ImageView;

      public class ZoomInZoomOut extends Activity implements OnTouchListener 
    {
        private static final String TAG = "Touch";
        @SuppressWarnings("unused")
        private static final float MIN_ZOOM = 1f,MAX_ZOOM = 1f;

        // These matrices will be used to scale points of the image
        Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
        Matrix savedMatrix = new Matrix();

        // The 3 states (events) which the user is trying to perform
        static final int NONE = 0;
        static final int DRAG = 1;
        static final int ZOOM = 2;
        int mode = NONE;

        // these PointF objects are used to record the point(s) the user is touching
        PointF start = new PointF();
        PointF mid = new PointF();
        float oldDist = 1f;

        /** Called when the activity is first created. */
        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
        {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.main);
            ImageView view = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
            view.setOnTouchListener(this);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) 
        {
            ImageView view = (ImageView) v;
            view.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.MATRIX);
            float scale;

            dumpEvent(event);
            // Handle touch events here...

            switch (event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) 
            {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:   // first finger down only
                                                    savedMatrix.set(matrix);
                                                    start.set(event.getX(), event.getY());
                                                    Log.d(TAG, "mode=DRAG"); // write to LogCat
                                                    mode = DRAG;
                                                    break;

                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP: // first finger lifted

                case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP: // second finger lifted

                                                    mode = NONE;
                                                    Log.d(TAG, "mode=NONE");
                                                    break;

                case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN: // first and second finger down

                                                    oldDist = spacing(event);
                                                    Log.d(TAG, "oldDist=" + oldDist);
                                                    if (oldDist > 5f) {
                                                        savedMatrix.set(matrix);
                                                        midPoint(mid, event);
                                                        mode = ZOOM;
                                                        Log.d(TAG, "mode=ZOOM");
                                                    }
                                                    break;

                case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:

                                                    if (mode == DRAG) 
                                                    { 
                                                        matrix.set(savedMatrix);
                                                        matrix.postTranslate(event.getX() - start.x, event.getY() - start.y); // create the transformation in the matrix  of points
                                                    } 
                                                    else if (mode == ZOOM) 
                                                    { 
                                                        // pinch zooming
                                                        float newDist = spacing(event);
                                                        Log.d(TAG, "newDist=" + newDist);
                                                        if (newDist > 5f) 
                                                        {
                                                            matrix.set(savedMatrix);
                                                            scale = newDist / oldDist; // setting the scaling of the
                                                                                        // matrix...if scale > 1 means
                                                                                        // zoom in...if scale < 1 means
                                                                                        // zoom out
                                                            matrix.postScale(scale, scale, mid.x, mid.y);
                                                        }
                                                    }
                                                    break;
            }

            view.setImageMatrix(matrix); // display the transformation on screen

            return true; // indicate event was handled
        }

        /*
         * --------------------------------------------------------------------------
         * Method: spacing Parameters: MotionEvent Returns: float Description:
         * checks the spacing between the two fingers on touch
         * ----------------------------------------------------
         */

        private float spacing(MotionEvent event) 
        {
            float x = event.getX(0) - event.getX(1);
            float y = event.getY(0) - event.getY(1);
            return FloatMath.sqrt(x * x + y * y);
        }

        /*
         * --------------------------------------------------------------------------
         * Method: midPoint Parameters: PointF object, MotionEvent Returns: void
         * Description: calculates the midpoint between the two fingers
         * ------------------------------------------------------------
         */

        private void midPoint(PointF point, MotionEvent event) 
        {
            float x = event.getX(0) + event.getX(1);
            float y = event.getY(0) + event.getY(1);
            point.set(x / 2, y / 2);
        }

        /** Show an event in the LogCat view, for debugging */
        private void dumpEvent(MotionEvent event) 
        {
            String names[] = { "DOWN", "UP", "MOVE", "CANCEL", "OUTSIDE","POINTER_DOWN", "POINTER_UP", "7?", "8?", "9?" };
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            int action = event.getAction();
            int actionCode = action & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK;
            sb.append("event ACTION_").append(names[actionCode]);

            if (actionCode == MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN || actionCode == MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP) 
            {
                sb.append("(pid ").append(action >> MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_ID_SHIFT);
                sb.append(")");
            }

            sb.append("[");
            for (int i = 0; i < event.getPointerCount(); i++) 
            {
                sb.append("#").append(i);
                sb.append("(pid ").append(event.getPointerId(i));
                sb.append(")=").append((int) event.getX(i));
                sb.append(",").append((int) event.getY(i));
                if (i + 1 < event.getPointerCount())
                    sb.append(";");
            }

            sb.append("]");
            Log.d("Touch Events ---------", sb.toString());
        }
    }
```

Add the `view` like this in `XML`:

```
<com.abc.ZoomInZoomOut
android:id="@+id/image"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

Comment: please can you give me all the libraries to import? and all the xml?

Comment: thank you but in this line setContentView(R.layout.main); i have error cannot resolve symbol'main' and this line return FloatMath.sqrt(x * x + y * y); i have error connot resolve methode'sqrt(float)'. @Android Geek

Comment: @S.Fochive here you will define the path of file  ZoomInZoomOut--> `com.abc.ZoomInZoomOut`. And you will get the imageview.

Answer (score 0):

google this `package`name

```
    package="it.sephiroth.android.library.imagezoom"
```

then import the library and create a class in your project

**Imports**

```
import it.sephiroth.android.library.imagezoom.ImageViewTouch;
import it.sephiroth.android.library.imagezoom.ImageViewTouch.OnImageViewTouchDoubleTapListener;
import it.sephiroth.android.library.imagezoom.ImageViewTouch.OnImageViewTouchSingleTapListener;
import it.sephiroth.android.library.imagezoom.ImageViewTouchBase.DisplayType;
import it.sephiroth.android.library.imagezoom.ImageViewTouchBase.OnDrawableChangeListener;
```

**ZoomActivity Class**

```
public class ImageZoomActivity extends Activity {

private static final String LOG_TAG = "image-test";
HorizontalListView listview1;
ImageViewTouch mImage;
Button mButton1;
Button mButton2;
CheckBox mCheckBox;
ArrayList<ImageListModel> arryNew = new ArrayList<ImageListModel>();
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.zoom_in_layout);        
    arryNew = (ArrayList<ImageListModel>) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("xyz");
    System.out.println("size of array "+arryNew.size());
    /*if(arryNew.size() > 0)
    {
    selectRandomImage(arryNew.get(0));
    }*/
    if(arryNew == null)
    {

    }
    else
    {
    //mImage.setImageResource(arryNew.get(0));
        Picasso.with(this).load(arryNew.get(0).getJpg())
        .placeholder(R.drawable.appicon).into(mImage);
    }
    listview1 = (HorizontalListView)findViewById(R.id.listview1);
    listview1.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
        float rawX;
        int mTouchSlop = ViewConfiguration.get(getApplicationContext())
                .getScaledTouchSlop();
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            switch (event.getActionMasked()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                v.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
                rawX = event.getRawX();
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                v.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(false);
                rawX = 0f;
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                if (Math.abs(rawX - event.getRawX()) > mTouchSlop)
                    v.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
                break;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
    HAdapter adapter1 = new HAdapter(arryNew);
    listview1.setAdapter(adapter1);
}


@Override
public void onContentChanged() {
    super.onContentChanged();
    mImage = (ImageViewTouch) findViewById(R.id.image);
    mImage.setDisplayType(DisplayType.FIT_IF_BIGGER);      
    mImage.setSingleTapListener(
        new OnImageViewTouchSingleTapListener() {
            @Override
            public void onSingleTapConfirmed() {
                Log.d(LOG_TAG, "onSingleTapConfirmed");
            }
        }
    );

    mImage.setDoubleTapListener(
        new OnImageViewTouchDoubleTapListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDoubleTap() {
                Log.d(LOG_TAG, "onDoubleTap");
            }
        }
    );

    mImage.setOnDrawableChangedListener(
        new OnDrawableChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDrawableChanged(Drawable drawable) {
                Log.i(LOG_TAG, "onBitmapChanged: " + drawable);
            }
        }
    );
}

@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
}

Matrix imageMatrix;
public void selectRandomImage(Integer arryImg) {                      
            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), arryImg);
            final DisplayMetrics metrics = getResources().getDisplayMetrics();                
            int size = (int) (Math.min(metrics.widthPixels, metrics.heightPixels) / 0.55);
            if (null != bitmap) {
                Log.d(LOG_TAG, "screen size: " + metrics.widthPixels + "x" + metrics.heightPixels);
                Log.d(LOG_TAG, "bitmap size: " + bitmap.getWidth() + "x" + bitmap.getHeight());
                mImage.setOnDrawableChangedListener(
                    new OnDrawableChangeListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onDrawableChanged(final Drawable drawable) {
                            Log.v(LOG_TAG, "image scale: " + mImage.getScale() + "/" + mImage.getMinScale());
                            Log.v(LOG_TAG, "scale type: " + mImage.getDisplayType() + "/" + mImage.getScaleType());
                        }
                    }
                );
                mImage.setImageBitmap(bitmap, null, -1, -1);
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Failed to load the image", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }          
}

private class HAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    ArrayList<ImageListModel> galleryitems = new ArrayList<ImageListModel>();

    public HAdapter(ArrayList<ImageListModel> arryNew) {
        super();
        this.galleryitems = arryNew;
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return galleryitems.size();
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return null;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    public View getView(final int position, View convertView,
            ViewGroup parent) {
        View retval = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.custom_zoom_items, null);
        ImageView image = (ImageView) retval.findViewById(R.id.imgItem);

          Picasso.with(ImageZoomActivity.this).load(galleryitems.get(position).getThumb())
        .placeholder(R.drawable.appicon).into(image);
        //image.setImageResource(galleryitems.get(position));           
          //Picasso.with(getApplicationContext()).load(galleryitems.get(position)).placeholder(R.drawable.appicon).into(image);
        retval.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {               
            @Override
             public void onClick(View v) {
                // mImage.setImageResource(arryNew.get(position));
                  Picasso.with(ImageZoomActivity.this).load(galleryitems.get(position).getJpg())
                .placeholder(R.drawable.appicon).into(mImage);
            }
        });
        return retval;
    }
   };
 }
```

**ImageListModel**

```
import java.io.Serializable;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class ImageListModel implements Serializable{
    String thumb,jpg;

    public String getThumb() {
    return thumb;
}

    public void setThumb(String thumb) {
    this.thumb = thumb;
}

    public String getJpg() {
    return jpg;
}

    public void setJpg(String jpg) {
    this.jpg = jpg;
    }
}
```

and use this class where ever you want to zoom